# Unzip (zip, tar, tar.bz2) file with python under python

Tags: python, directory, unzip

I am trying to make a script for unzipping a .tar file with ***python*** under ***windows***, the .tar file contains a folder **127.0.0.1:8004**

If I do manually, I can extract the folder 127.0.0.1:8004, this folder takes another name 127.0.0.1_8004

I try the following code:

```
import tarfile
import os

path= r'C:\temp\Temp'
os.chdir(path)
finalName= os.listdir(".")[0]
finalName

if finalName.endswith("tar"):
    tar = tarfile.open(finalName, "r:")
tar.extractall()
tar.close()
```

But when I try my code, I become an error

Output: NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid:

```
  File ".\Test.py", line 14, in <module>
    tar.extractall()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2024, in extractall
    self.extract(tarinfo, path, set_attrs=not tarinfo.isdir(),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2065, in extract
    self._extract_member(tarinfo, os.path.join(path, tarinfo.name),
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2139, in _extract_member
    self.makedir(tarinfo, targetpath)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\tarfile.py", line 2168, in makedir
    os.mkdir(targetpath, 0o700)
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] Der Verzeichnisname ist ungültig: '.\\measurements_18_Oct_2023_07h_46m_33s\\with_x6mt_no_roadrunner\\R8_First_Measurements\\127.0.0.1:8004'
```

Comment: `:` is not a valid character for directories, so you need to rename the directory. Have a look at [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: @MauriceMeyer You should answer this question, so that it doesn't keep popping up unanswered. :)